# ajax crossdomain post to php kohana 3.2 not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, kohana

I have 2 (local) subdomains: `kohana.local.com` and `wordpress.local.com`. jQuery plugin (.js) is located on kohana.local.com domain and takes care of rating articles and retrieving rate count on both domains. Controller_Rating extends Controller. Method (action_getrating) has following code (kohana 3.2):

```
if($this->request->post() && $this->request->is_ajax()){
    $this->auto_render = FALSE;
    echo "{$_REQUEST['callback']}(".json_encode($data).")";
}
```

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://kohana.local.com/rating/getrating",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: { some_id: id },
    success: function(json){
            //do something
    }
});
```

When ajax call gets issued from kohana.local.com, everything works great. If it's issued from wordpress.local.com `$this->request->is_ajax()` is false, and method is not "post", but "get" somehow. What is the reason for this, and how to make it work? Post is required and is_ajax is good for security and validation.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
post to jsonp is not possible, so i can't use this approach. i'll have to try to find the solution in the direction of json

Comment: JSONP uses GET, and its not AJAX call. Remove post&is_ajax checks, add CSRF token for security.

Comment: hehe, you've beat me to it. i was editing the question when you posted this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `json` dataType, so you don't need to use callbacks. Just add header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to server which requests are made (kohana.local.com).

All domains are allowed:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Or specify allowed domain:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://wordpress.local.host
```

Spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-access-control-20080912/#access-control-allow-origin

---

Multiple domain solution: [Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains)

Comment: thanks for the answer. although i can detect post method with your suggestion, kohana doesn't keep the session, and i can't trace logged user any more, so i can't use this. in any other case this would probably be the solution. thanks for the effort and useful information!

Comment: and i can't give you +1 on answer, my rep is too low :)